# how to print value of arguments in C

Tags: c

This is a very simple question:

I know how to print values of argv[2] in C but I don't know how to print values of argv[2][1] in C. Can anybody tell me?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you realize that `argv[2][1]` is a "second character of a second argument"? That means for command line `myprogram 123 xyz`: `argv[2] == "xyz"` and `argv[2][1] == 'y'`.

Comment: You should put at least a minimal effort into learning. Honestly, if you can't find the solution to this problem (it would have only taken 1 minute of googling or just reading the very first chapter of a beginner C tutorial), then you are either very lazy or not prepared to start out with programming yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
printf("%c\n", argv[2][1]);
```

`argv` is declared `char* argv[]`, so `argv[2][1]` is of type `char`, use `%c` in `printf` to print.

If you run `program_name hello world`, you will print `o` which is the second character of the second argument.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that argv is a pointer to pointer to char.

so argv[2] is a pointer to char, and 
argv[2][1] is a character.

To print a char, you need to use the `%c` conversion specifier in `printf` rather than `%`s.